# Export database to multiple files in same job Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I need to export some database of arround 180k objects to JSON files so I can retain data structure in certain way that suits me for later import to other database. However because of amount of data, I wanto to separate and group data based on some atribute value from database records itself. So all records that have `attribute1=value1`, I want to go to `value1.json`, `value2.json` and so on.
However I still haven't figured out how to do this kind of job. I am using `RepositoryItemReader` and `JsonFileWriter`.

I started by filtering data on that attribute and running separate exports, just to verify that works, however I need to do this so I can automate whole process and let it work.

Can this be done?

Comment: How are you intending to handle that dynamism? Would you pass `value1`, `value2` as a job parameter?  Or are you planning to have a tasklet that calculates all distinct values prior to the actual processing? This is key to correctly answer your question.

Comment: Calculate all distinct values. Query to database to fetch all values to that attribute. @MahmoudBenHassine

Comment: Thank you for the update. I added an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. Here are a couple of options:

#### Option 1: parallel steps

You start by creating a tasklet that calculates the distinct values of the attribute you want to group items by, and you put this information in the job execution context.

After that, you create a flow with a chunk-oriented step for each value. Each chunk-oriented step would process a distinct value and generate an output file. The item reader and writer would be step-scoped bean and dynamically configured with the information from the job execution context.

#### Option 2: partitioned step

Here, you would implement a `Partitioner` that creates a partition for each distinct value. Each worker step would then process a distinct value and generate an output file.

Both options should perform equally in your use-case. However, option 2 is easier to implement and configure in my opinion.

Comment: Do you mean to explicitely use spring batch flow, or I can use regular job and loop through all values and add steps with `next` method of job builder? Would that work? I do not understand what you meant by parallel steps? Because there could be couple of hundred distinct values, so performance could be issue if those ran parallel?

Comment: Also is it possible to access that job context value which I saved from tasklet step inside job builder, because if I understood you right I need to loop through those values and add steps dynamically?

Comment: Assuming readers/writers will accept every distinct value from job context, how do I call that from level up so I can configure every needed step(for every value)?

Comment: option 1 would work well if the number of distinct values is not too high. And yes, you create tasklets dynamically by using step scoped beans.

Comment: I was thinking of storing all distinct values as list of Strings as single parameter. What I do not know is how to access context in job definition so I can add all dynamic steps. Like this:
`@Bean
    public Job serviceCasesPPExportJob() { return jobs.get("serviceCaseExportJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).start(calculatorTasklet()) // add all dynamic steps here.build();
    }` Sorry for the confusion, but I am still new to Spring batch.

Comment: I've implemented solution with partitioner. Thanks @MahmoudBenHassine. However I am still qurious in first solution just for education purposes. :D